# TTL of a dynamic arp entry in windows (not base time, actual time)

Tags: windows, cache, arp, ttl

When I run `arp -a` on my cmd I get a list of arp entries. The dynamic entries expire when their timer expires and then they are deleted from the arp cache. How can I see how much time a certain entry has left?

**I am not talking about the "base reachable time" that is used for calculating this value like in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1345144/what-is-the-default-cache-refresh-rate-of-windows-8-and-ubuntu) question, I'm talking about the actual value for each entry, i.e if an entry is added 33 seconds before another one, then I expect that the timers will be different with a 33 second difference.**

For clarification: If the base time for an entry is 100 seconds and 2 entries are added to the cache, 10 seconds apart, then I want to be able to display the **time left** for each entry until it is deleted from the cache, which should be 10 seconds apart, for example 30 seconds and 20 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! When your previous question was closed, please do not just repost it. I have also reviewed your first attempt at posting this question, and although I cannot answer it, I cannot tell the difference between this repost and the original one.

Comment: hi! thanks for your comment. The difference is that the first one was closed because it was not clear enough and the person that closed it didn't understand the difference between it to the one he claimed already answers it. The difference is that there are 2 values at play here: the first and the one Im not interested in is the base time which is how much time is set for each entry when it is created. the second is the actual time that is left for the entry. for example, if all the records start with 60 seconds, i want to be able to display the 50 seconds left after 10 seconds.